# hiltViewModel<ViewModel>() vs by viewModels()

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

(This might not be relevant, but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere and it's been bugging me)

While creating and reviewing applications that use dagger-hilt I noticed that most people, to create an instance of their viewModel class, use something like

```
val viewModel: XViewModel by viewModels()
```

and some use

```
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<XViewModel>()
```

is there any difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will create a view model instance using hilt but the difference is that this one below is for creating view model for a fragment, you can't use it in a composable screen:

```
val viewModel: XViewModel by viewModels()
```

And the second one is new and comes with jetpack compose, you can use it inside a composable screen and it will create a view model instance that will stay alive as long as your screen is in navigation stack:

```
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<XViewModel>()
```